# Bash move file to folder with same first 6 digits in name

Tags: bash, loops, move

i have many folders like *123456_files* and many files like *123456.dzi*,
i want to move the **123456.dzi** file into the **123456_files** Folder
(same .dzi file into same *_files Folder)

i tried this code, but it removes the .dzi ending and does`not move it.

```
for f in *.dzi; do
  [[ -f "$f" ]] || continue
  dir="${f}"
  mv "$f" "$dir"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in *.dzi; do
  [[ -f "$f" ]] || continue
  dir="${f%.dzi}"
  mkdir "${dir}_files"
  mv "$f" "${dir}_files"
done
```

Comment: Thanks, but does´nt work. Its renaming the .dzi file. Probably i wrote it not cleary.
I just want to move the file, not renaming it. Or do i misunderstand you?

Comment: I added a `mkdir`.

Comment: i dont need the mkdir, as the folder already exists. but its working now, i think the third line is the changer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
for f in *.dzi; do [[ -d "${f%.*}_files" ]] && mv "$f" "${f%.*}_files"; done
```

The `${variable%pattern}` syntax removes the shortest match of pattern from the end of a variable, i.e., it removes the extension in this case.

If the directory is absent, you can use something like this to create it:

```
for f in *.dzi; do mkdir -p "${f%.*}_files"; mv "$f" "${f%.*}_files"; done
```